# App missing (disappear) from my device

Tags: android

When I add the following code in the `AndroidManifest` the app is missing (disappears) from my device.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https"
                  android:host="www.example.com"
                  android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"/>

</intent-filter>
```

If I don't add this code the app is installed and appears as it should be BUT I get warning:

> App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent filter.

I already did research from [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173545/app-is-not-indexable-by-google-search-android-lint) but still my problem is different.

EDIT:
Here is all my manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:fullBackupContent="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                      android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme"
                      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https"
                  android:host="www.example.com"
                  android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"/>

    </intent-filter>

            <activity android:name=".AnimationScreenActivity"
                      android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme"
                      android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>


            </activity>

        </application>
```

Comment: post your complete androidmanifest.xml please

Comment: Thanks not even valid format  activity > intent-filter > activity ???

Comment: 1st : you're not closing you're intent filter at the right place .                    2nd: I think as the error says you're not using any activity before` <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />`

Comment: @Harisali I just mistyped here the closing, I corrected it here but in my code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @Harisali help, the solution is to separate it in two `<intent-filter>` like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                      android:host="www.example.com"
                      android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"/>

       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing your intent filter right

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                      android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme"
                      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: I just mistyped here the closing, I corrected it here but in my code is correct.

Comment: try seperating your intent filters like this ``<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter> <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https"
                  android:host="www.example.com"
                  android:pathPrefix="/gizmos"/>

    </intent-filter>``

Comment: Indeed that solved my problem. Is weird though that i have to separate it in two different intent-filters but it solved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app and run the code, sometimes the old package might be overwritten.