# Application Tag in manifest show me [App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent filter]

Tags: android, xml, manifest

i'm trying to add notification service in my application after add same line like `service` in `manifest`  .... Tag  `Application` show me this messegs i don't have any idea what suppose to mean this messege ,

[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="ddd">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/animal" />
    <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Splashscreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173545/app-is-not-indexable-by-google-search-android-lint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App is not indexable by Google Search (android lint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173545/app-is-not-indexable-by-google-search-android-lint)

Answer (score 0):

> **Your Solution is here**

*You can't write below code within multiple activity tag as per google index.*

*So, remove this code from all activity tags and just type it once on the main activity tag*

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```