# How to fix Android manifest.xml in android studio to enable indexing?

Tags: android, android-studio

App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent filter. See issue explanation for more details. less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:Adds URLs to get your app into the Google index, to get installs and traffic to your app from Google Search.

But I Have already considered one activity with an action view intent filter.
Please help.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity"/>



</application>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing support for Firebase App Indexing (android lint)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173545/missing-support-for-firebase-app-indexing-android-lint)

Comment: you do not have any activity with action view intent filter  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />`

Answer (score 2):

Add android.intent.action.VIEW into your launcher activity like below.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

</intent-filter>
```

Comment: This seems the correct answer, if you want to add such a functionality to your app

Answer (score 1):

Just add inside application tag

```
<application
tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"    **// Add this Statement Here,**
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity"/>



</application>
```